# Including a CSS file in an EJS layout that includes another EJS file

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, ejs

I'm using Bootstrap 5 for the style of my first website. I created a navbar using Bootstrap and I want to change the background color of it using a CSS file. I have a boilerplate ejs file that I use in every page (as a layout) that includes the navbar and a footer. I want to change some stuff in the navbar file using the CSS file I created. I tried to link the CSS file in the boilerplate file and the navbar file in so many ways but it doesn't work. It doesn't change the style of all, I even tried to change the style of a paragraph (that doesn't have anything of bootstrap) and it didn't work. Here's my code:
The boilerplate.ejs:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Adoptify</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/views/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
    <%- include('../partials/navbar') %>
        <main class="container mt-3">
            <%- body %>
        </main>
        <%- include('../partials/footer') %>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

The navbar.ejs:

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg" data-bs-theme="dark" id="test">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Adoptify</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/animals">Animals</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/animals/new">New Animal</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/reviews">Reviews</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The CSS file:

```
#test {
    background-color: rgb(151, 255, 135) !important;
}
```

Some express code:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.